# ETL flow in Fact tables

Tags: data-warehouse, etl, dimensional-modeling, facttable

I've got a simple theoretical question...

If we discuss the principles, elements, design and implementation of a typical ETL flow for a dimension table then, in my understanding, (in short) I'd say something like : *first data is extracted from source system, then transformation is applied (so the data maps the Dimensional Model) and then it is loaded into the dimension entities. With a Type-2 change method, each entry in the dimension is simply the data (description) of the entity.*

Now, how can you describe the very same things for the Fact tables? I am confused in here... I know that the Fact tables contain Partial Primary Keys of the dimensions connected to it, and also some attributes that summarize some data. But what do the Fact tables contain as a general understanding? And how can you explain the ETL flow for a Fact table. Please, provide me with some simplified explanation, perhaps your own words, of how you understand it...